Prevent data corruption in shared memory in Python?
I am currently working on a multiprocessing Python program where each process writes its index to shared memory as a consecutive 4-byte integer. and there is a reader that reads other processes' indexes without any locks(due to the speed limitations). Because I am not using any synchronization primitives, I am worried that reader process might read corrupted data (e.g., the first 2 bytes of one index and the last 2 bytes of another index) due to the memory being written byte by byte.
Reading previous indexes is not a problem in my case; I just need to ensure that the read index is historically valid.
I have observed that on macOS, this issue does not occur (perhaps due to Python or macOS-specific behavior). However, the program needs to run on other operating systems such as Windows and Ubuntu as well.
I created a small example bellow.
import time
import random
import struct
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

def writer(rank, shared_memory):
    index = 0
    while True:
        byte_array = struct.pack("i", index)
        shared_memory.buf[rank * 4: rank * 4 + 4] = byte_array
        index += 1
        time.sleep(random.random())

def reader(shared_memory, size):
    while True:
        indexes = struct.unpack(f"{size}i", shared_memory.buf[:size*4])
        print(f"Read indexes: {indexes}")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = 10
    shared_memory = shared_memory.SharedMemory(
            create=True, size= 4 * size
        )
    
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")

    processes = []
    for i in range(size):
        p = ctx.Process(target=writer, args=(i, shared_memory))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    reader_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=reader, args=(shared_memory, size))
    reader_process.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    reader_process.join()


Any advice or examples to ensure data integrity would be appreciated!

« Because I am not using any synchronization primitives, ... » / « any advice ». Sorry for stating the obvious here, but the first advice would be « then, use synchronization primitives ». Is there any reason not to? (you haven't said it). Their whole point is to avoid data corruption.

Sure, you can otherwise bet that there won't be any corruption, as you have seen on your mac. Because writing the 4 bytes ID (depending on how bytearray affectation works. I don't know the internal) is maybe done with a single 32-bit MOV operation. And therefore, there won't be any task switch during the operation. But that would be relying on some implementation detail you don't control.

If the data is large enough, there is no way to prevent it from being corrupted. So your options are: 1) prevent corrupted data from being read (use synchronization), or 2) prevent corrupted data from being used (use parity checks to validate data integrity).

Sorry, I updated the question. The reason is speed. In my case, these reads need to be very fast (in my actual implementation, multiple readers access the same data for their processes). However, when I add synchronization primitives, my whole system slows down and cannot utilize all resources efficiently. I initially tried to find an atomic increment like in C++, but I couldn't find a similar operation in Python. @chrslg

Please include all of your requirements in your question, not in the comments. Your example consists of multiple writers and a single reader, but you just said there are multiple readers. Also, you said you want the readers to be very fast, but is it okay if the writers are slow?

Also, have you tried lock.acquire(block=False)? Is it still too slow for you?

It would be very interesting to know your timings with and without "protection" (e.g., Lock)

Usually, memory transfers will happen in chunks with rather large size, e.g. in 64KB blocks. I would strongly assume that your 4 bytes will be written/read in an atomic operation.
I'd recommend to do a stress test with lots of random writes and reads of known numbers. If you don't see any problems there, you're probably good.
Other than that, you can only roll some kind of custom locking. E.g. reserve the last bit of the last byte for locking. When writing, first write 0x80 to the last address, then write the payload data. When reading, if (last read byte) & 0x80 != 0, you know that you read a half-written index and need to retry.
In the usual LSB order of integers, this bit is the flag bit - i.e. your indexes must not be negative, to not interfere with the "lock" marking.
Code example:
def writer(rank, shared_memory):
    index = 0
    while True:
        byte_array = struct.pack("i", index)
        # Set "Locked" flag for this index
        shared_memory.buf[rank * 4 + 3] = 0x80
        shared_memory.buf[rank * 4: rank * 4 + 4] = byte_array
        index += 1
        time.sleep(random.random())

def reader(shared_memory, size):
    while True:
        indexes = struct.unpack(f"{size}i", shared_memory.buf[:size*4])
        # "Optimistic" locking: assumes that indexes are not locked most of the time.
        if any((index & 0x80000000) for index in indexes):
            print("Read while locked, retry.")
            continue
        print(f"Read indexes: {indexes}")
        time.sleep(1)


A stress test like that could easily be implementation and system specific, I wouldn't trust it to be portable.

Indeed, it only makes sense if there is a finite, enumerable set of target platforms.

Added a couple of log lines to assist in 'debugging'
import time
import datetime
import random
import struct
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

def writer(sz, rank, shared_memory):
    index = 0
    while True:
        byte_array = struct.pack("i", index)
        shared_memory.buf[rank * 4: rank * 4 + 4] = byte_array
        print( f'WRITER:{datetime.datetime.now()} rank:{rank} {struct.unpack(f"{sz}i", shared_memory.buf[:sz*4])}' )
        index += 1
        time.sleep(random.random())

def reader(shared_memory, size):
    while True:
        indexes = struct.unpack(f"{size}i", shared_memory.buf[:size*4])
        print(f"READER:{datetime.datetime.now()} size:{size} Read indexes: {indexes}")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = 10
    shared_memory = shared_memory.SharedMemory(
            create=True, size= 4 * size
        )

    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")

    processes = []
    for i in range(size):
        p = ctx.Process(target=writer, args=(size, i, shared_memory))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    reader_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=reader, args=(shared_memory, size))
    reader_process.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    reader_process.join()

redirect the output to a file when testing, you'll also do well to sort the log by time sort -k2 should be enough, that hopefully will show/highlight any issues. I think the 1second sleep it probably a partial reason why I didn't find any noticeable corruption ( i ran it for ~30mins ).
still, doing 'proper synchronisation' is the way to go.
